# How can I improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, asking-questions

I'm referring to this question: [SQL-Server Merge Statement with .NET DataTable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/sql-server-merge-statement-with-net-datatable)

I've given it a couple days to see what happened after I asked it initially.  There's been very little traffic, no votes and no comments seeking further information.  I'm curious what the community thinks about this question and how I can improve it to be of more use to the community.  I feel it's decently formatted and relatively well thought out but I'm open to any suggestions.

Questions:

1. Is this question on topic here, or should it be moved somewhere else?
2. Is this question lacking anything specific which would help it get answered?
3. Is this question too specific to be of use to this community?

Getting an answer to the linked question isn't the primary goal of this Meta question.  The code works and is currently in use.  I'm more interested in being better at asking good questions on this site and would appreciate any advice in that direction.

Comment: Oh wow. I honestly don't know. It looks like a good question to me. It's clear and concise... well written. Perhaps a catchy title would have garnered more views. I fear your question might have just slipped through the cracks. I'm interested in hearing what others have to say about it.

Comment: @RubberDuck thank you.  That's why I asked about the question being too specific, maybe that was keeping some people from answering.  Also, catchy titles aren't my specialty.  :)

Comment: It most likely did slip through the cracks, and the site can be slow on the weekend. Not every question will receive quick attention, and that's not always about the question itself.

Comment: It's a good question. It's perfect the way it is. Looks pretty hard to answer though, which is the most likely explanation for the lack of answers so far. Hang tight, I'm sure it will get looked at, from now. Somebody might even stick a bounty on it. ;-)

Comment: Have you tried to share the question in other circles?  Either using the share links at the bottom of your question or just posting the URL in online communities you are involved in (twitter I've found is one of the more helpful since Google indexes tweets so quickly, it is likely to get a broader audience).

Comment: @xDaevax No, I haven't tried that.  I wasn't really looking to expand the scope of this question outside of the StackExchange community.  I'd rather try to improve it within this community so that I know what is expected here.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is this question on topic here, or should it be moved somewhere else?

Yes, is on topic.

> 2. Is this question lacking anything specific which would help it get answered?

Just reviewers =). I'm sure people will find something to edit it with, but it looks better than a code dump.

> 3. Is this question too specific to be of use to this community?

Hmmm... I don't know. SQL is pretty hard to review, actually. Or at least it feels that way to me.